# R - setting up my own CRAN repository

Tags: r, package, cran

I want to set up a local CRAN repository . I want to put just one package in this repository ( let's call it MyPackage ). The reason I'm doing this is that I want to share this package with people at my company. By the way - we all use Ubuntu Linux. 
I have already done this:

- I have a web server ( BOA web server ) and made a web folder called R. Made folder src and contrib.
- In the contrib folder I put my package MyPackage ( tar.gz) plus the PACKAGES file.

However, when I do this:

```
install.packages("MyPackage", repos = "127.0.0.1/R" )
```

it does not work ;

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository [ ]
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘MyPackage’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

Can you guys guide me a bit and tell me what is the correct folder structure ?
Thanks.

Comment: The online repositories contain `built` R packages. You would need to `build` the package (which creates a `.tar.gz` file. Look at the directory structure of an online repository. [CSIRO melbourne](http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/).

Comment: If you don't mind the package being public you could always host it on github and use the function `install_github` from the devtools package to do the installation.  This is quite easy to do and requires less work to make changes to the package.

Comment: Conversely you could use bitbucket which operates very similar to bit bucket.  `install` from devtools has functionality similar to dason's suggestion but installs the local repo.  Here's a youtube on how to do this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGeCCxdZsDQ  but is way more than your question asked for.  from 6:10 on it's pertinent to you.

Comment: You're looking for more detail, but about what?  That is, what in the FAQ is unclear?

Comment: Hi guys, I followed the instructions in the FAQ and I just can't get it to work , spent several hours trying to set it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might just need to specify the URL properly; `http://127.0.0.1/R`.

Also, make sure you can access that URL in your browser.

Answer (score 13):

See "[Section 6.6 Setting up a package repository](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository)" of the R Admin manual.

*Edit some three+ years later*: We now have the [drat package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) which automates creating a repository, and can use GitHub in a clever way to host it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [miniCRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html) works good for me. There are few advantages to using miniCRAN to create the repository:

- **Security:** Many R users are accustomed to downloading and installing new R packages at will, from CRAN or one of its mirror sites.
- **Easier offline installation:** To install package to an offline server requires that you also download all package dependencies, Using miniCRAN makes it easier to get all dependencies in the correct format.
- **Improved version management:** In a multiuser environment, there are good reasons to avoid unrestricted installation of multiple package versions on the server.
- **Use other R Package Indexes:** You may wish to make packages available from public repositories other than CRAN, e.g. BioConductor, r-forge, OmegaHat, etc.
- **Prepare own R repo:** You may wish to add custom in-house packages to your repository.

See intro:

1. [Using miniCRAN to create a local CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html)
2. [Create a local package repository using miniCRAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/create-a-local-package-repository-using-minicran#bkmk_manual)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is revealed in this statement:
"In the contrib folder I put ... the PACKAGES file."

The PACKAGES file is an index for the repository. You need to *create* that file after your package files are placed in the repository directory. Don't copy and paste the PACKAGES file from another repository.

If I were you, here's what I would do. First, add the following code to your .Rprofile for a local repository:

```
utils::setRepositories(ind = 0, addURLs = c(WORK = "127.0.0.1/R"))
```

Restart R after changing your .Rprofile.

`ind = 0` will indicate that you only want the local repository. Additional repositories can be included in the `addURLs =` option and are comma separated within the character vector.

Then, create the repository index:

```
tools::write_PACKAGES("127.0.0.1/R/src/contrib", verbose = TRUE)
```

After you do that, you should be able to generate a data frame that has a list of all the packages. For example, `my_packages <- available.packages()`.

If you see packages in your repository data frame, then install using the following code:

```
install.packages("MyPackage")
```

[For more information, please see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544966/15370142)