# Trouble with my own repository: it can't find my package in R 2.15.2

Tags: r, cran

I've created a CRAN repository on my server, [cran.gforge.se](http://cran.gforge.se), it used to work like a charm before 2.15.2, but now I get an error complaining that the package doesn't exist.

My code for installing my Gmisc package:

```
reps = c("http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/CRAN",
         "http://cran.gforge.se")
install.packages("Gmisc", repos=reps, dependencies=TRUE)
```

This gives the error:

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘Gmisc’ is not available (for
>   R version 2.15.2)

I've tried to look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927266/r-setting-up-my-own-cran-repository?rq=1) that seems to be very similar but without any help. [The manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository) is a little scarce on the subject but currently I do the following write_PACKAGES before uploading:

```
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES("C:\\Software\\cran", verbose=TRUE, subdirs=TRUE, type="win.binary")
write_PACKAGES("C:\\Software\\cran", verbose=TRUE, subdirs=TRUE, type="source")
write_PACKAGES("C:\\Software\\cran\\src\\contrib", verbose=TRUE, subdirs=TRUE)
write_PACKAGES("C:\\Software\\cran\\bin\\windows\\contrib\\2.15", verbose=TRUE, subdirs=TRUE, type="win.binary")
write_PACKAGES("C:\\Software\\cran\\src\\contrib\\2.15", verbose=TRUE, subdirs=TRUE, type="source")
```

I've also tried the suggested solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132111/my-package-doesnt-work-for-r-2-15-2):

```
options(install.packages.check.source = FALSE)
install.packages("Gmisc", repos=reps, dependencies=TRUE)
```

Since I have a  parallel source code, this shouldn't be a problem or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try and put `Gmisc_3.5.tar.gz` into `/src/contrib` and then execute
`install.packages("Gmisc", repos="http://cran.gforge.se", type="source")`?

Comment: Thank you! I thought that for some reason I need to have 2.15 in the source too, but boy was I wrong :-D It actually works now with the binary.

Comment: Good to hear I could help... As a sidenote, I think you need only one PACKAGES file, in the root folder. Happy r'ing!

Comment: Ok, the manual states: "Each terminal directory must also contain a PACKAGES file". Your probably right because it seems strange that I need three different write_PACKAGES() calls...

Comment: Tested, didn't work with only PACKAGES in the root dir. Thanks anyway!